# I cannot find sched.c in ubuntu

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to learn real-time scheduling, so our professor asked us to change sched.c. But I even find it. My OS is ubuntu LTS 12.04. I searched it online. Someone said there is no sched.c in ubuntu. Is he right? What file does ubuntu use to schedule? tick-sched.c? BTW: I am a linux rookie, could some tell me where I need to start? Thanks a lot.

Comment: You will need to download the kernel source and learn how to build and install it.  In the meanwhile, take a look here: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/sched/

Comment: Which kernel version does your professor want you to work with?  Which version do you have?  If you look at the 2.6 kernels on kernel.org it seems there is a sched.c while in the 3.x kernels this is done differently as the files were first moved to kernel/sched and then reshuffled further.  Likely you'll want to run such experiments in a virtual machine anyway, so you can just install an older version on it.

Comment: I am using 3.13.1. I only find /kernel/sched folder in it. So you guys mean that there is no sched.c for 3.x kernels? How can I change the schedule of the OS in 3.x kernels? Is sched.c repalced with sched/ or sched/core.c?

Comment: @rpfly3 kernel/sched/core.c looks like a very good place to start.  BTW, when replying on stackoverflow you should use the '@' symbol and the person that you are replying to so you get their attention.

Comment: @PeterL. Thanks a lot. I was wandering how to reply to someone. Thanks.